# How do wallets generate new key-pairs?

Tags: wallets, private-key, account-generation

The probability of collision for any two randomly chosen private-public key pairs is notoriously low. However, I wonder whether wallets or key generators use random or pseudorandom numbers to generate the keys. If it is the latter, there is some more predictability and higher collision rate, correct?

Comment: Random doesn't exist in the regular computers. It's always pseudo random as if you know all the parameters you can reproduce the outcome. But the pseudo random generator is based on very hard to predict inputs (mouse, time, ...) and provides a fair level of randomness that, with the generated content length, is physically impossible to game right now.

Comment: I could have rephrased my question whether they use pseudo-random numbers or random numbers and even though you mentioned that computers allegedly don't do random, you answered it yourself that in this case they do use random numbers. Mouse and time are not pseudo-random.

Comment: But feel free to post the answer @NicolasMassart, and maybe with a link to the code in metamask (repo) or any of the wallet generators, that they do use external input to seed their random number generators

Comment: Well mouse and time based random generators are not real random as if you set your clock to the exact time and do the exact same mouse moves, then you have the exact same random number. A real random would be unpredictable even if we know all the initial states. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator and note the important part is "suitable for use in cryptography". You can also read more about the enthropy sources here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71813/where-does-dev-random-get-its-entropy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real randomness doesn't exist in the regular computers (not talking here about quantum based randomness).

It's always pseudo random as if you know all the parameters you can reproduce the outcome.

Mouse and time based random generators are not real random but pseudo random as if you set your clock to the exact time and do the exact same mouse moves and have all the devices exactly work the same way and control the temperature and many things, then you have the exact same random number.
A real random would be unpredictable even with the exact same initial state. But we don't do that with regular home computers or you will have to dive into QRNG (quantum random number generator) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

But the pseudo random generator (PRNG) that we use in home and family computers is already based on very hard to predict inputs (mouse, time, other devices that can generate noise, heat, whatever is hard to predict...) and provides a cryptographically suitable level of randomness that, with the generated content length, is physically impossible to game right now (I mean with the currently known state of computing technologies).

The more you use the computer, the more the entropy increases. So for instance it heats, you make more moves on the mouse, type more on the keyboard, have more things go through the processor,... so wait for a fair amount of time of using a computer before using a PRNG and the randomness will be even better.

See more on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator and note the important part is "suitable for use in cryptography".

You can also read more about the entropy sources of the linux `/dev/random` here (but others are working mostly the same way) https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71813/where-does-dev-random-get-its-entropy